# Why cant find db0bjects

Tags: javascript, module, sequelize.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create a "currency system" for a discord bot by following a guide, but when i try to start the bot it says Error: Cannot find module './dbObjects' my app.js code is this:
javascript

New error
The code of objects.js is this the error says: sequelize.import is not a funcion

```
const Sequelize = require ('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
   host: 'localhost',
   dialect: 'sqlite',
   logging: false,
   storage: 'database.sqlite',
});

const Users = sequelize.import('models/Users');
const CurrencyShop = sequelize.import('models/CurrencyShop');
const UserItems = sequelize.import('models/UserItems');

UserItems.belongsTo(CurrencyShop, { foreignKey: 'item_id', as: 'item' });

Users.prototype.addItem = async function(item) {
   const userItem = await UserItems.findOne({
       where: { user_id: this.user_id, item_id: item.id },
   });

   if (userItem) {
       userItem.amount += 1;
       return userItem.save();
   }

   return UserItems.create({ user_id: this.user_id, item_id: item.id, amount: 1 });
};

Users.prototype.getItems = function() {
   return UserItems.findAll({
       where: { user_id: this.user_id },
       include: ['item'],
   });
};

module.exports = { Users, CurrencyShop, UserItems };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error means that the probleme com from the directory here:

```
const { Users, CurrencyShop } = require('./dbObjects');
```

you should change that by

```
const { Users, CurrencyShop } = require("./models/dbObjects.js');
```

it should work but i'm not sure! can you add more details on what is the guide you're using?

also, for your code, it's better to use an switch case statement, instead of if, elif

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, anyway the guide is this https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/currency.html#making-a-currency-system

Comment: Did you create the file "dbObjects.js" ?

Comment: okey, what's the full path of your code, can you give me all the files location, like a screen ?

Comment: Okey, i got it, i edited the answer for you! try the new code  !

Comment: Ok, now it worked fine but now another error pops out :cry: TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function

Comment: of curse here it is

Comment: /home/daniel/Scrivania/Bot/models/dbObjects.js:10
const Users = sequelize.import('models/Users');
                              ^

TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/daniel/Scrivania/Bot/models/dbObjects.js:10:31)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)

Comment: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/daniel/Scrivania/Bot/app.js:4:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)

Comment: Okey, that means that ypu have a probleme in your dbObject.js

Comment: you can make man anwer correct, and create a new post. i'll follow it to help you again

Comment: I can't because I reach the limit :(

Comment: okey just add const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); at the top of your code

Comment: There is but I pasted the code in a wrong way give me a sacond

Comment: you can try to add like dot and slash but i'mnot sure,  i don't think that i could help for this one

const Users = sequelize.import('./models/Users');
const CurrencyShop = sequelize.import('./models/CurrencyShop');
const UserItems = sequelize.import('./models/UserItems');

Comment: I'll try tomorrow